# Which of Terry Tao's co-authors on compressed sensing consulted for Renaissance Technologies?

Tags: history

On [Feb 11 2018 on Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-secret-behind-Renaissance-Technologies-Can-mathematics-really-be-used-to-bring-high-returns-to-investors/answer/Vladimir-Novakovski/comment/54182963), Vladimir Novakovski commented

> Terry is Tier One in the RenTec world. His coauthor on compressed sensing did some consulting for them, actually.

Who's this co-author?

Comment: TT has two coauthors on this article: Emmanuel Candes or Justin Romberg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The is the article you are looking for:

[Stable Signal Recovery from Incomplete and Inaccurate Measurements

Emmanuel Candes, Justin Romberg, Terence Tao](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0503066)

It provided the basis for compressed sensing.